# Symfony Forms: add a link to a label

Tags: forms, symfony1, widget

I am looking for a way to add an HTML link () in a symfony form, right below an element label. I have trying widgetSchema, but I run over difficulties.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Check these docs: http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/03-Forms-for-web-Designers

Instead of rendering your form as so:

```
<?php echo $form ?>
```

You probably want to render it more granularly:

```
<?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields() ?>
<?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors() ?>
...
<?php echo $form['foo']->renderLabel() ?><a href="#">Link</a><?php echo $form['foo']->render() ?>
<?php echo $form['foo']->renderError() ?>
...
```